# Counting number of different words in a txt file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Well, I do not know much about programming at bash, I'm new at it so I'm struggling to find a code to iterate all the lines in a txt file, and count how many words are different.
Example: If a txt file has "Nory was a Catholic because her mother was a Catholic"
So the result must be  7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ grep -o '[^[:space:]]*' file | sort -u | wc -l
7
```

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton, I like the answer (I upvoted it) but I believe it'd be better with a `+` to say "one or more non spaces" rather than the `*` which says "zero or more"... It's possible your answer handles that due to the -o flag (I'm not at a shell to test) but I think itd be more semantically correct if nothing else if edited.

Comment: If I used `+` instead of `*` then I'd need to add `-E` to support EREs or make other changes, I think `*` is fine.

Comment: Ok then, fair enough

Answer (score 2):

Sure. I assume you are ok with defining "words" as things that are separated by space? In which case, try something like this:

```
cat filename | sed -r -e "s/[ ]+/ /g" -e "s/ /\n/g" | sort -u | wc -l
```

This command says:

- Dump contents of filename
- Replace multiple spaces with a single space
- Replace spaces with newline
- Sort and "uniquify" the list
- Print out the count of lines

Per the comment, you can technically get away without using cat if you'd like, with the following:

```
sed -r -e "s/[ ]+/ /g" -e "s/ /\n/g" filename | sort -u | wc -l
```

Further, from another comment, you could optionally use `tr` (importantly with it's -s flag to handle repeated spaces) instead of `sed` with something like:

```
tr -s " " "\n" < filename | sort -u | wc -l
```

The moral of the story is there are several ways this kind of thing can be accomplished, not to mention the other full answers that are given here :-) My personal favorite answer at this point is Ed Morton's which I've upvoted accordingly.

Comment: Congratulations, you win today's "Useless use of cat" award :-) Try `sed -r -e "s/[ ]+/ /g" -e "s/ /\n/g" filename | sort ...` instead.

Comment: Ha. Fair enough :p

Comment: S'ok, it works even with that niggle so deserves an upvote.

Comment: `sed -r -e "s/[ ]+/ /g" -e "s/ /\n/g"` is the same as `tr -s ' ' '\n'`

Comment: I removed the wc -l to see how it works and I found out that it works but some equal words weren't removed because they are separeted by tabs, it was like this 
Ex:
word
 word
  word

Comment: correct. If you use Ed Morton's solution it will handle any white space separators. This one here simply handles " " separation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also lowercase the text so words compares regardless of casing.

Also filter words with the `[:alnum:]` character class, rather than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that is only valid for US-ASCII, and will fail dramatically with Greek or Turkish.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "The uniq words are the words that appears at least once, regardless of casing." |
  # Turn text to lowercase
  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
  # Split alphanumeric with newlines
  tr -sc '[:alnum:]' '\n' |
  # Sort uniq words
  sort -u |
  # Count lines of unique words
  wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so, with comments:

```
echo "Nory was a Catholic because her mother was a Catholic" |
# tr replace
# -s - squeeze
# -c - complementary
# [a-zA-Z0-9_] - all letters, number and underscore
# but complementary set, so all non letters, not numbers and not underscores.
# replace them by newline
tr -sc '[a-zA-Z0-9_]' '\n' |
# and sort unique and display count
sort -u | wc -l
```

Tested on [repl bash](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/OutrageousUnsightlySale).

Decided to use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, because this is how GNU sed [\w extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html) matches a word.

Comment: Why do you need sed there? tr can squeeze runs of non-letters before replacing them

Comment: To remove empty lines. Ex. `Hello, my name is kamil.` will result in an empty line from `,<space>` beeing substituted by two `\n\n`.

Comment: `echo Hello, my name is kamil. | tr -cs [:alpha:] '\n'` does not generate empty lines..

Answer (score -1):

```
cat yourfile.txt | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -c > youroutputfile.txt
```

xargs -n1 = put one word per line

sort = sorts

uniq -c = counts occurrences of distinct values

[source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-count-occurrences-of-unique-words-in-a-file-519248/)

Comment: Using `xargs` would work strange. For example `quote: "this is a quote"` would count 2 words. `xargs` parses quotes.

Comment: oh weird, why would it only count two?

Comment: Are you missing a `cat` at the start of that command? In addition, doesn't that give each word with its individual quantity rather than the total quantity?

Comment: second guessed myself after seeing the other answer and removed it

Comment: `xargs` (by default) is quote aware, it parses quoted input as one argument. So `echo '123 "this is in quotes"' | xargs -n1` will output two lines.

Comment: @TravisG : Another problem with `xargs`, besides the quotes, is that it takes punctuation as part of the words. If the input contains something like `A+B,C` (with no spaces), this is one single input word for xargs, not three. A solution would be to pipe the input first through `tr` and replace everything, which is not a letter, by a space, and **then** feed it to `xargs`.